# sqlite combine column data based on count

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, count

I'm not sure if this really possible to do in sqlite as I've looked around.

Here's what I have as a part of a table (NONE are PK, FK, or IDs, just regular text data):

```
    col1 col2 col3
    foo1 bar1 foobar1
    foo1 bar1 foobar2
    foo1 bar1 foobar3
```

I was able to select the count of foo1 and bar1by doing

```
    SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*)
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY col1
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

to find the duplicate columns, but my end goal is to combine the data in column 3 into one column, delimited by slashes i.e  foobar1/foobar2/foobar3, and delete all but 1 of the selected rows so the output would be:

```
    col1 col2 col3
    foo1 bar1 foobar1/foobar2/foobar3
```

This is pretty difficult I think to do solely in SQLite, but maybe it is possible? If not, how would you do this in a a regular programming language like Java? I am doing Android programming so I am able to access the database and do queries.

Comment: I just found this, seems like exactly what you are asking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `SQLite` supports `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, GROUP_CONCAT(col3) col3
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ff458/2)

And if you need to change the delimiter from a "," to a "/", then use:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(col3, '/') col3
```

Comment: thanks! you really helped me out a lot. I thought it would be a lot harder than that.

Comment: nice, didn't know that existed.